# ASP.NET MVC & caching of EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I heart about caching of EF results and that it's by default. I have the following repository:

```
public class Model1Repository
{
    private NEOGOV_IdeasEntities _dataContext;
    public Model1Repository()
    {
        _dataContext = new NEOGOV_IdeasEntities();
    }

    public List<Status> Statuses()
    {
        var query = from i in _dataContext.Statuses select i;
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

and the following controller with method:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private NEOGOV_Ideas.Models.Model1Repository _repository;
    public TestController()
    {
        _repository = new NEOGOV_Ideas.Models.Model1Repository();
    }

    public ActionResult Test1()
    {
        _repository.Statuses();
        _repository.Statuses();
        _repository.Statuses();
        _repository.Statuses();

        return View();
    }
}
```

as I understand, after first call of Statuses method results should be cached but I see in SQL profile:

```
exec sp_reset_connection 
go
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
[Extent1].[StatusName] AS [StatusName]
FROM [dbo].[Statuses] AS [Extent1]
go
exec sp_reset_connection 
go
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
[Extent1].[StatusName] AS [StatusName]
FROM [dbo].[Statuses] AS [Extent1]
go
exec sp_reset_connection 
go
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
[Extent1].[StatusName] AS [StatusName]
FROM [dbo].[Statuses] AS [Extent1]
go
exec sp_reset_connection 
go
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
[Extent1].[StatusName] AS [StatusName]
FROM [dbo].[Statuses] AS [Extent1]
go
```

what is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have found out, EF does not cache result sets, although I have been meaning to take a look at this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32